# JSON в MySQL - стоит ли пробовать?

Tags: json, mysql

Есть система, которая с помощью тригеров выполняет некий функционал в MySQL. Сейчас у меня появилась задача расширить этот функционал, но для этого необходимо дополнительно хранить данные в табличках.

Одно из возможных расширений - добавить столбец, и там хранить массив в JSON формате, и в самом СУБД обрабатывать (парсить) этот столбец (знаю что в MySQL возможно распарсить JSON массив)

**Вопрос:** Стоит ли вообще так извращаться и пробовать реализовывать это? Или это будет бесполезный опыт?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я думаю не стоит... JSON важен интересен, когда есть необходимость передать и получить объект. Ну а какой к черту объект интересен на стороне сервера MySQL? Это будет только лишний оверхед